# In SRP POV, Should converting raw data to an object be in a dedicated method?

Tags: single-responsibility

I have a function that retrieves raw data from the database and returns an object which represents this data.

Should the conversion between the raw data and the object be written in that method or should I dedicate a separate method for the conversion, according to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with a separate method, maybe even a separate class. The reason is not only SRP, but [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) too. Of course, if it is always the same format that the data is to be converted to and there is little chance of that format changing, then there is really no need to overdesign the code.